# Generate numbers from 0000 to 9999 with 4 digits

Tags: r

I am having a bit of trouble changing the format of my integer. I need to display numbers from 0000 to 9999 (10000 numbers)in R Language. Would someone know how could I do this displaying the 4 digits (0001  0002...9998  9999)?

Comment: `sprintf("%04d", 0:9999)`.

Comment: And `formatC(0:9999, width = 4, flag = "0")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make strings with extra zeros "padded" on the left with `str_pad()`

```
 library(stringr)
 stringr::str_pad(0:9999, width = 4, side = "left", pad = "0")

  [1] "0000" "0001" "0002" "0003" "0004" "0005" "0006" "0007" "0008" "0009" ...
```